# PHP Echo shorthand is removing all forward slashes

Tags: php, shorthand

Here is a section of my code which should add the background image to a label, but for some reason when I start using `<?=` shorthand, all of the forward slashes are being removed:

```
<label for="<?=$result_id?>_checkbox" id="<?=$result_id?>_label" style="background-image:url("<?=$img?>");" />
```

Here is the code that generates the URL:

```
$img = $_SESSION['ROOT_DIR']."data/images/".$folder."/".$result_imageset."/".str_replace(" ", "%20", $result_jpg);
```

This is what that `$img` variable generates:

```
http://localhost:1234/ppa/data/images/20140130/0/RMEuvh3.jpg
```

**Edit:**

```
echo var_dump(ini_get('short_hand_tags'));
```

Produces:

> bool(false)

Although, the following works...

```
<div class="jpg"><?=$result_jpg?></div>
```

Comment: Probably because "short_hand_tags" isn't the ini variable, "short_open_tags" is. And also, according to http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, the short echo tags are always enabled. You said it removes the slashes, please show us exactly what is being generated.

Comment: Strange, now it is working, the issue may have been with Chrome's  Inspect Code feature. Viewing the source shows it as working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the *source code* of the page being generated. It works for me, in the sense that forward slashes are not removed.

However there is problem with your code:

`style="background-image:url("<?=$img?>");"`

You have **double quotes within double quotes**. That will not work :)

you want this instead

`style="background-image:url('<?=$img?>');"` <-- inner double quotes replaced with single quotes.

Other than that your code renders as expected.